# Change axis from hours to months in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginning programmer, and I'm working on plotting data in matplotlib. The plot is supposed to show nitrogen content over the course of hours. However, as the model runs over several months, it would be better to show months instead of hours on the x-axis.

[The current plot can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amkb8.png)

So, my question is: How do I change the x-axis from hours to months?

Thank you! The code is shown below.

---

```
plt.figure()
plt.title( 'Nitrogen content')
plt.plot(sugar_kelp_field.N_content_list)
plt.plot(720, 0.0150, 'bo')
plt.plot(1440, 0.0205, 'bo')
plt.plot(2160, 0.0265, 'bo')
plt.plot(2880, 0.0283, 'bo')
plt.plot(3600, 0.0234, 'bo')
plt.plot(4320, 0.0181, 'bo')
plt.plot(5040, 0.0142, 'bo')
plt.plot(5760, 0.0097, 'bo')
plt.plot(6480, 0.0083, 'bo')
plt.xlabel("time [h]")
plt.ylabel("nitrogen content [fraction of dw]")

plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by the same scale? Same distance between points of the plot?
And by month you mean 30 days?

Comment: Hi Alessandro, let me rephrase that: I would like to change the x-axis from hours to months. So dividing it into steps of 720 hrs (30*24). By month I mean 30 days, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can get an approximation of the number of months by dividing the number of hours by `730`:

[image: hours-to-months-formula]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def hours_to_months_approximation(hours: int) -> float:
    return round(hours / 730, 2)


def main() -> None:
    plt.figure()
    plt.title('Nitrogen content')
    plt.plot(sugar_kelp_field.N_content_list)
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(720), 0.0150, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(1440), 0.0205, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(2160), 0.0265, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(2880), 0.0283, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(3600), 0.0234, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(4320), 0.0181, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(5040), 0.0142, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(5760), 0.0097, 'bo')
    plt.plot(hours_to_months_approximation(6480), 0.0083, 'bo')
    plt.xlabel('time [months]')
    plt.ylabel('nitrogen content [fraction of dw]')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have hours and h values in lists:

```
hours=[720, 1440 ,2160, 2880, 3600, 4320, 5040, 5760, 6480]
v=[0.0150, 0.0205, 0.0265, 0.0283, 0.0234, 0.0181, 0.0142, 0.0097, 0.0083]
```

the `calendar` allows you to get the months names:

```
import calendar
m_str=[calendar.month_name[int(x/(30*24))] for x in hours]  
>>>['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September']
```

Then this piece of code:

```
plt.figure()
plt.title( 'Nitrogen content')
plt.plot(m_str, v, 'bo')
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

will get the desired result:

[image]